# Rspec: Run a test only if session condition is true

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Say I have a share example group. This group tests to make sure the correct menu exists on every page on the site.

The problem is the menu is not identical on each page, merely nearly identical. The exception is that the menu does not include a link to the page you are currently testing. As such, that test needs to be skipped. I have, as a component of the testing suite, a full list of all the links.

What would be the best way to test this? Normally, I would just have the test conditionally generated, but since it depends on the context (the page identity) of where the shared example is included, by the time I have that bit of required information it is too late to do so. I could have a test like 
    link_list.each do |link|
    it "should exist on this page unless this page is on the exception list" do
      if(@session.not_on(list))
        @session.should not_have_link(link)
      else
        @session.should have_link(link)
      end
    end
    end

but I think ambiguous tests of this sort are best avoided. By this point, I will KNOW what behaviour to expect, since I can check to see whether the session page is or is not on the list, but I don't know how to express that.

What can I do to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: Please make your description clearer. I can't quite seem to understand the scenario. However, test setup show be deterministic and easy to build/understand. If that's not so, maybe you have a setup problem.

Comment: I've added an example. While what you said is true, DRY is also kind of important, right? I don't want to have to test for 30 links on each page, and then have one link changed later and need to change it for tests for each of the 80 pages that use that menu...